# Genericity VS Polymorphic data structures

Tags: c++

I was learning about polymorphism and stuff around it in C++. I came across an example/homework that says something about polymorphic data structure. 
I'm pretty familiar with **genericity** and how you can use it to create for example lists of different data types (creating a template, etc), but how is this different from the **polymorphic data structure**? 
Is it just the same thing or what is the difference?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Template polymorphism is resolved at compile time.